# Is it safe to use weak delegate in block in MRC?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, delegates

```
Message *m = [msg retain];
dispatch_queue_t queue = _handle_queue;
__block id delegate = self.protocol_delegate;
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onReceive:)]) {
        [delegate onReceive:m];
    }
});
```

I have a MRC objective-c file, which declare a weak delegate,

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<ProtocolDelegate> protocol_delegate;
```

Is the delegate will reset to nil if the delegate is released?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it will not autoreset to nil if the delegate released.

The essential of `ARC` is that the compiler will only manage the life-cycle/memory of the internal object rather than the external object. While, for `MRC` objective-c file, all the object will need your management.

Altought the `protocol_delegate` is declared as weak, it is the object file which make up the final executable which in turns depends on the .m file. So the `weak` tag is ignored. In order to get the weakptr, you'd need to make [a wrapper around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40966421/how-to-make-weak-self-in-mrc).