# How to make weak self in MRC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, weak-references

```
Message *m = [msg retain];
dispatch_queue_t queue = _handle_queue;
__block ProtocolDriver* blockSelf = self;
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    if (blockSelf.protocol_delegate && [blockSelf.protocol_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onReceive:)]) {
        [blockSelf.protocol_delegate onReceive:m];
    }
});
```

I have a MRC objective-c file, which need run some code in block asynchronously.

But I thought the `blockself` is not safe since it is not weak pointer, Should I change it to true weak pointer.

```
@interface WeakPtr : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id realObj;
@property (nonatomic, assign) bool released;
@end
@implementation WeakPtr
@end
```

set the released when the MRC-object is dealloced, and test it in block

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) WeakPtr* selfPtr;
- (id)init{
    ...
    self.selfPtr = [[[WeakPtr alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.selfPtr.realObj = self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    ...
    self.selfPtr.released = true;
}

-(void)pump: (Message *)msg
{
    Message *m = [msg retain];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = _handle_queue;

    __block WeakPtr* weakSelf = self.selfPtr;
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        if (!weakSelf.released && [weakSelf.protocol_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onReceive:)]) {
            [weakSelf.protocol_delegate onReceive:m];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can use __unsafe_unretained.

Comment: @New16 can __unsafe_unretained gaurantee that `weakself` auto reset to nil when it is dealloced.

Comment: All your delegates should be declared as `assign`. So, that it doesn't retain and will reflect whatever the value you `assign`.

Comment: Good read: [Zeroing Weak References in Objective-C](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, definitely.

1) make a ARC weak pointer wrapper class.

```
@interface WeakPtr : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id realObj;
@end
@implementation WeakPtr
@end
```

2) use the ARC weak pointer wrapper in MRC to wrap the strong pointer.

```
-(void)pump: (Message *)msg
{
    Message *m = [msg retain];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = _handle_queue;
    WeakPtr* weakPtr = [WeakPtr new];
    weakPtr.realObj = self;
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        if ([weakPtr.realObj.protocol_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onReceive:)]) {
            [weakPtr.realObj.protocol_delegate onReceive:m];
        }
        [weakPtr release];
    });
}
```

Another option is `-fobj-weak` compiler flag.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer: You can't. The `weak` qualifier is a feature of ARC. In MRC, the type is assign, and it's equivalent to ARC's `unsafe_unretained` type.

MRC does not have an auto-niling weak type.

### Edit:

Ok, perhaps "you can't" was too strong. Better to say:

MRC doesn't support auto niling weak references and you would have to handle it with app-level code, or a library that does it for you.

Comment: You can. I know there are libraries does this and I wrote similar code use associated object to observe `dealloc` call and nil the weak pointer.